# How to pass the this pointer to a task inside a class?

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp32, multitasking

I am creating a library to manage our wifi network connection on many ESP32 devices.

Inside my library, i have a task that is looping with a 1 second pause started with an xTaskCreate inside my .begin() function. The problem is that i can't start the task if i haven't make it static in my .h file. So once the task is declared as static, i don't have access to the this-> pointer inside this task. Is there anyway i can send the this-> pointer inside my task like in parameters or something like that ?

Here is some code:

```
class EraWiFi{
    public:
        EraWiFi();
        /*!
        * @brief Initialize WiFi
        * @return Returns true if successful
        */

        bool begin(fs::FS &fs);
        /*!
        * @brief Start EraWiFi service
        * @return Returns true if successful
        */

        void downloadWiFi();

    private:
        static void wifiTask(void * parameter);
};


bool EraWiFi::begin(fs::FS &fs){
    File file = fs.open("/WiFi.json", FILE_READ);
    if(file){
        DynamicJsonDocument wifi(2048);
        DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(wifi, file);
        file.close();
        if (!error){
            Serial.println("We have a VALID WiFi.json configurations file!");
            Serial.println("Adding wifi networks:");
            for (JsonArray arr : wifi.as<JsonArray>()){
                Serial.print("SSID: ");
                Serial.print(arr[0].as<char*>());
                Serial.print(", KEY: ");
                Serial.println(arr[1].as<char*>());
                wifiMulti.addAP(arr[0].as<char*>(), arr[1].as<char*>());
            }
        }else{
            Serial.println("We don't have a VALID WiFi.json configurations file!");
        }
    }else{
        Serial.println("There is no WiFi.json configurations file!");
    }
    wifiMulti.addAP("Testing", "1234");
    xTaskCreate(
        this->wifiTask,    // Function that should be called
        "WiFiTask",   // Name of the task (for debugging)
        10000,            // Stack size (bytes)
        (void*)&this,            // Parameter to pass
        1,               // Task priority
        NULL   // Task handle
    );
    return true;
}



void EraWiFi::downloadWiFi(){
    Serial.println("Downloading WiFi.json from ErabliTEK Server.");
    HTTPClient http;
    // Send request
    http.useHTTP10(true);
    String url = "https://testing.testing.com/wifis/getWiFi/";
    http.begin(url);
    int httpResponseCode =  http.GET();
    if(httpResponseCode == HTTP_CODE_OK){
        // Parse response
        DynamicJsonDocument doc(2048);
        DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, http.getStream());
        // Disconnect
        http.end();
        if (!error){
        File file = fs.open("/WiFi.json", FILE_WRITE);
        if(file){
            // Serialize JSON to file
            if (serializeJson(doc, file) == 0) {
            Serial.println("Error saving WiFi.json!");
            Serial.println(http.getString());
            }else{
            Serial.println("Succesfully saved WiFi.json!");
            }
        }
        // Close the file
        file.close();
        }else{
        Serial.println("Error downloading WiFi.json");
        }
    }else{
        Serial.println("Problem connecting to " + url + " with http code: " + String(httpResponseCode));
    }
}



void EraWiFi::wifiTask(void * parameters){
    bool wifiConnected = false;
    for(;;){
        uint8_t wifiStatus = wifiMulti.run();
        if((wifiStatus != WL_CONNECTED) and wifiConnected) {
            wifiConnected = false;
            Serial.println("WiFi not connected!");
        }else if((wifiStatus == WL_CONNECTED) and !wifiConnected){
            wifiConnected = true;
            Serial.println("WiFi Connected.");
            Serial.print("SSID: ");
            Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
            Serial.print("KEY: ");
            Serial.println(WiFi.psk());
            Serial.print("IP Address: ");
            Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
            EraWiFi::downloadWiFi();
        }
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share actual code the demonstrates the problem. Your description may be meaningful to you but it's not to us. Edit the question to include the code that works but doesn't do what you need, and the code that you're trying to make work that does what you need with the text of the errors you get when you try to build it or run it.

Comment: You can pass an instance of the class as a parameter and access members with ->, but that may not be the best solution. Please post some code or provide more details about your situation.

Comment: I have edited the post with the code. my problem is in the EraWiFi::wifiTask when i try to call the downloadWiFi() function, i can't use this->downloadWiFi() since i have to declare the wifiTask as static to be able to start it as a Task.

Comment: Are you able to pass an instance of EraWiFi as a parameter? Your function declaration might look something like: static void wifiTask(EraWiFi* eraWifiObject, void * parameter); and in the function, your downloadWiFi() call would look like eraWifiObject->downloadWiFi();. I feel like there might be a better way to handle this, though. How about a static object outside of this class? The only private member is this static function, so it might make it more clear to separate that functionality out entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already doing that, you just don't realize it. Have a look at the [FreeRTOS documentation on `xTaskCreate()`](https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html) which explains how the fourth parameter `pvParameters` is a void pointer that gets passed on to the new task as its (one and only) input parameter.

The commented line here means you're taking the address of your EraWiFi object and passing it to the task:

```
    xTaskCreate(
        this->wifiTask,
        "WiFiTask",
        10000,
        (void*)&this,  //< Pointer gets forwarded to the task
        1,
        NULL
    );
```

To use the pointer inside your task, you only need to cast it back from `void*`:

```
void EraWiFi::wifiTask(void * parameters){
    EraWifi* p = static_cast<EraWifi*>(parameters); //< That's the same pointer
    p->someMethod();
...
```

PS. Also note (before you poke at the same object from different threads, possibly causing hard-to-find bugs) that FreeRTOS provides excellent inter-thread communication facilities - the [queues](https://www.freertos.org/a00018.html) and [task notifications](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-notification-API.html) often being the most useful ones. Check out their [tutorial/book](https://www.freertos.org/fr-content-src/uploads/2018/07/161204_Mastering_the_FreeRTOS_Real_Time_Kernel-A_Hands-On_Tutorial_Guide.pdf) for an explanation.

Comment: I would have never thought of passing the whole this pointer. Thanks this saved me a lot of trouble!